# Is there any reason why adding a footer to my emails is triggering some spam software to filter it?

Tags: email, spam

This seems an odd one but my emails are some how triggering various recipients spam software. This only happens if my email has a footer one it, if i send it without the footer the emails get delivered fine.

Any idea why this is happening? It seems to be the bigger email providers who do this, like Yahoo! and BT.

Answer (score 1):

You will be triggering "spammy" characteristics - maybe with HTML code contained in your footer, maybe with images included there, maybe just with wording (just add some references to "Viagra" and "Rolex watches cheap" and see what happens).

In fact, it will be not that easy to tell without knowledge of the current filtering ruleset and having the complete message including the headers from the receiver side. But you might just post an example message source including headers that you've sent and that didn't get through. If you got an NDR, it would be of interest as well.